# Combine an Array object with scalar value within a scalar? Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to combine an item from an Array list with a scalar `$range`. Here's how I'm trying to do it.

```
my $rowinc = 2;
my $colarray = @collet[0];
my $range = $colarray $rowinc;
chomp $range;


$sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = $ir;
    shift @collet;
$sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = $sn;
    shift @collet;
$sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = (join(", ", @parts));
    shift @collet;
$sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = $ref;
    $rowinc++;
    unshift @collet, 'C';
    unshift @collet, 'B';
    unshift @collet, 'A';
```

I've tried multiple ways of doing this and to no avail. Here's the error I receive while running this particular snippet.

```
Scalar found where operator expected at gen1.pl line 87, near "$colarray $rowinc
"
        (Missing operator before $rowinc?)
syntax error at gen1.pl line 87, near "$colarray $rowinc"
Execution of gen1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm assuming that the array can't be used in that manner to denote the value for $range. The problem I'm running into is that I am using Win32::OLE to manage my excel spreadsheets because it gives me the ability to open an already existing spreadsheet. But the drawback is I cannot enter my cell ranges as integers ($row,$col) I've tried this just incrementing `$row` and `$col` I want to be able to manage this effectively instead of using a bunch of if else and what not.

What I've tried to do is my `@collet = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');`
tells me which column to print in if I start at 0 it should start printing in A col. which is good and then every time it prints in a column it shifts right so now `@collet[0]` should be 'B'. I know this isn't the best method but I've changed my original method to this in hopes to solve the issue. any help would be awesome!

Here's my full script for some context.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin
#manage IR/SRN/Parts Used
#Written for Zebra
#Author Dalton Brady
#Location Bentonville AR

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE qw( in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;


$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;    #Die on errors

#different types of units worked on, trying to name the worksheet 
#after one depending on user input have yet to add that func.
my @uut = ('VC5090', 'MK2046', 'MK2250', 'MK4900', '@pos');

my $ref = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', localtime(); #create the datestamp
my $i   = 0;                         #increment counter for why loop
my $n   = 0;                         #increment for do until loop
my $xfile = 'X:\dataTest\data.xls';  #location of excel file
my $book;     #place for the workbook to exist
my $sheet;    #worksheet exists here
my $ex;       #a place to hold the excel application
my $row = 2;  #track row in which data will 
              #be placed with the do until loop 
my $col = 1;
my @parts ; # store the different parts as a list within 
            # an area (to be written to the spreadsheet)
my @talk = ( 'IR:', 'SN:', 
             '#of Parts Used: ', 'PN:', 
             'Units Completed: ');
my @collet = "A" .. "Z"


# start an instance of excel

$ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$ex->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;    #turn off alerts/textboxes/saveboxes

#check to see if excel file exists if yet open it, if not create it
if (-e $xfile) {
  $book  = $ex->Workbooks->Open($xfile);
  $sheet = $book->Worksheets("Test");
  $sheet->Activate();
}
else {
  $book = $ex->Workbooks->Add()
    ;    #create new workbook to be used because we couldn't find one
  #########SETUP YOUR EXCEL FILE#############
  $sheet = $book->Worksheets("Sheet1");
  $sheet->Activate();
  $sheet->{Name}                             = "Test";
  $sheet->Cells("a1")->{HorizontalAlignment} = x1HAlignCenter;
  $sheet->Cells("b1")->{HorizontalAlignment} = x1HAlignCenter;
  $sheet->Cells("c1")->{HorizontalAlignment} = x1HAlignCenter;
  $sheet->Columns("a")->{ColumnWidth}        = 20;
  $sheet->Columns("b")->{ColumnWidth}        = 20;
  $sheet->Columns("c")->{ColumnWidth}        = 30;
  $sheet->Range("a1")->{Value}               = "IR Number";
  $sheet->Range("b1")->{Value}               = "Serial Number";
  $sheet->Range("c1")->{Value}               = "Parts Used";
  $sheet->Range("d1")->{Value}               = "Date";

  $book->SaveAs($xfile);    #Save the file we just created
}

# ask for how many units user will be 
# scanning or has completed to be scanned
print $talk[4] ; 

#unit count tracker, determines how many times the do while loop runs
my $uc = <>; 
do {

  print $talk[0];    #ask for the IR number
  my $ir = <>;
  chomp $ir;
  print $talk[1];    #ask for uut Serial Number
  my $sn = <>;
  chomp $sn;
  print $talk[2];

# ask for the number of parts used, to regulate 
# the parts list storage into the @parts array
  my $pu = <>;

  while ($i < $pu) {

    print $talk[3];
    my $scan = <>;
    chomp $scan;
    push @parts, $scan;
    $i++;
  }

  my $rowinc   = 2;
  my $colarray = @collet[0];
  my $range    = $colarray $rowinc;
  chomp $range;


  $sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = $ir;
  shift @collet;
  $sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = $sn;
  shift @collet;
  $sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = (join(", ", @parts));
  shift @collet;
  $sheet->Range($range)->{Value} = $ref;
  $rowinc++;
  unshift @collet, 'C';
  unshift @collet, 'B';
  unshift @collet, 'A';


} until ($n == $uc);


# save and exit
$book->SaveAs($xfile);
$book = $ex->WorkBooks->Close();
undef $book;
undef $ex;
```

Comment: `my $range = $colarray $rowinc;` is not valid Perl code, like the error says. I am not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Based on the first example in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE#EXAMPLES), `Range` takes a pair of cell names separated by a colon, e.g. `$sheet->Range("A8:C9")`. Do you know how to include variables in a string?

Comment: @TLP I'm trying to combine $colarray with $rowinc like I want to take the value A in colarray and combine it with the integer in $rowinc making a "range" to print in i.e. A2. I don't need an actual range (A8:C9) but I couldn't figure out how to print to a specific cell without it.

Comment: If you want `$range` to contain a string like `"A2:"` why wouldn't you just do: `my $range = "$collet[2]$rowinc:";`?

Comment: I'm trying to print in columns A B C D in order and then move to the next row after the final column is printed in. I was trying to use `$range` to do that by combining my list item stored in @collet with an integer denoting the row. Making '$sheet->Range($colarray$rowinc)' or $sheet->Range(A2). Sorry this isn't very clear

Comment: @G.Cito this is my first time using perl, and to be honest I started using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. There was a point where i tried to use a scalar inside "" but It would just keep printing the variable not the actual value. I was trying to avoid this

Comment: Let me see if I can get this working thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: @HeadyGains Since you're just starting out with Perl, I would recommend running through one (or several) [modern Perl tutorials](http://perl-tutorial.org/#index3h1). It's good to understand the fundamentals before trying to do more complex things.

Comment: @HeadyGains  I left in your error but reformatted your code so it does less side scrolling here on SO.   I did change one part of your code to use  perl's `"" .. ""`range feature which helped with the side scrolling. See if you can find it ;-) I agree with @ThisSuitIsBlackNot on the tutorials.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for all the help, I'm sorry I didn't ask my question properly and that my code was all muddled! To work I go!

Comment: @G.Cito I like what you did there, and just from that I should def. do alot of tutorials. Thanks for the change and again for all the help!